# Verify continuous condition with time

Tags: python, multithreading, time, concurrency, python-multithreading

I would like to develop a python program that, starting from a moment of time, wait 60 seconds before performing an action. Another feature that must have the program, is that if I update the initial time, it must start to check the condition. I thought about doing it with threads, but I do not know how to stop the thread and get it started again with the new start time.

```
import thread
import time


# Define a function for the thread
def check_message (last, timer):
    oldtime = time.time()
    print oldtime
    # check
    while time.time() - oldtime <= 60:
    print (time.time() - oldtime)
    print "One minute"+ str(time.time())
    return 1

# Create two threads as follows
try:
    named_tuple = time.localtime() # get struct_time
    time_string = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", named_tuple)
    thread.start_new_thread(check_message , (time_string, 60))
except:
    print "Error: unable to start thread"

while 1:
    pass
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking times in a loop is probably not necessary here and wasteful since you can put a thread to sleep and let the kernel wake it up if the time has come.
The threading library provides [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) for such use cases. The difficulty in your case is, that you cannot interrupt such a sleeping thread to adjust the interval after which the specified function should be executed.

I'm using a custom manager-class `TimeLord` in my example below, to overcome this limitation. `TimeLord` enables "resetting" the timer by canceling the current timer and replacing it with a new one.
For this purpose `TimeLord` contains a wrapping intermediate worker-function and a "token"-attribute, which must be popped by a running timer-instance to execute the specified target-function.

This design guarantees unique execution of the specified target-function since `dict.pop()` is an atomic operation. `timelord.reset()` is effective as long the current timer has not started its thread and popped the `_token`. This approach can not totally prevent potentially ineffective starts of new timer-threads when trying to "reset", but it's an uncritical redundancy when it happens since the target function can only be executed once.

This code runs with Python 2 and 3:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer, current_thread


def f(x):
    print('{} {}: RUNNING TARGET FUNCTION'.format(
        datetime.now(), current_thread().name)
    )
    time.sleep(x)
    print('{} {}: EXITING'.format(datetime.now(), current_thread().name))


class TimeLord:
    """
    Manager Class for threading.Timer instance. Allows "resetting" `interval`
    as long execution of `function` has not started by canceling the old
    and constructing a new timer instance.
    """
    def worker(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.__dict__.pop("_token") # dict.pop() is atomic
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None):
        self.func = function
        self.args = args if args is not None else []
        self.kwargs = kwargs if kwargs is not None else {}
        self._token = True
        self._init_timer(interval)

    def _init_timer(self, interval):
        self._timer = Timer(interval, self.worker, self.args, self.kwargs)
        self._timer.daemon = True

    def start(self):
        self._timer.start()
        print('{} {}: STARTED with `interval={}`'.format(
            datetime.now(), self._timer.name, self._timer.interval)
        )

    def reset(self, interval):
        """Cancel latest timer and start a new one if `_token` is still there.
        """
        print('{} {}: CANCELED'.format(datetime.now(), self._timer.name))
        self._timer.cancel()

        # reduces, but doesn't prevent, occurrences when a new timer
        # gets created which eventually will not succeed in popping
        # the `_token`. That's uncritical redundancy when it happens.
        # Only one thread ever will be able to execute `self.func()`

        if hasattr(self, "_token"):
            self._init_timer(interval)
            self.start()

    def cancel(self):
        self._timer.cancel()

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self._timer.join(timeout=timeout)
```

---

```
def run_demo(initial_interval):

    print("*** testing with initial interval {} ***".format(initial_interval))
    tl = TimeLord(interval=initial_interval, function=f, args=(10,))
    tl.start()

    print('*** {} sleeping two seconds ***'.format(datetime.now()))
    time.sleep(2)

    tl.reset(interval=6)
    tl.reset(interval=7)
    tl.join()
    print("-" * 70)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    run_demo(initial_interval=5)
    run_demo(initial_interval=2)
```

Example Output:

```
*** testing with initial interval 5 ***
2019-06-05 20:58:23.448404 Thread-1: STARTED with `interval=5`
*** 2019-06-05 20:58:23.448428 sleeping two seconds ***
2019-06-05 20:58:25.450483 Thread-1: CANCELED
2019-06-05 20:58:25.450899 Thread-2: STARTED with `interval=6`
2019-06-05 20:58:25.450955 Thread-2: CANCELED
2019-06-05 20:58:25.451496 Thread-3: STARTED with `interval=7`
2019-06-05 20:58:32.451592 Thread-3: RUNNING TARGET FUNCTION
2019-06-05 20:58:42.457527 Thread-3: EXITING
----------------------------------------------------------------------
*** testing with initial interval 2 ***
2019-06-05 20:58:42.457986 Thread-4: STARTED with `interval=2`
*** 2019-06-05 20:58:42.458033 sleeping two seconds ***
2019-06-05 20:58:44.458058 Thread-4: RUNNING TARGET FUNCTION
2019-06-05 20:58:44.459649 Thread-4: CANCELED
2019-06-05 20:58:44.459724 Thread-4: CANCELED
2019-06-05 20:58:54.466342 Thread-4: EXITING
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Note, with interval=2 the cancelations after two seconds had no effect, since the timer was already executing the target-function.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to do the check outside of the thread, so that the main loop executed a thread every 60 seconds that does X job:

```
import threading
import time

# Define a function for the thread
def check_message():
    print("One minute"+ str(time.time()))
    return 1

last_execution = time.time()
while 1:
    if time.time() - last_execution < 60:
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        last_execution = time.time()
        threading.Thread(target=check_message).start()
        # Python2:
        # import thread
        # thread.start_new_thread(check_message)
```

I swapped the code for a syntax that works in Python3 since I don't have Python2 installed. But the overall idea should work the same in both version.