# Check if Timer.cancel is called in unit test

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-unittest

I'm using the `threading.Timer` package to execute a method after x seconds. However, in some cases I want to execute this method earlier and cancel the timer (so it isn't called twice). *How do I unit test this?*

I want to know if the timer has stopped so that the method is not called anymore. I am now using the following code, unfortunately the `is_alive still` returns `True`

```py
from threading import Timer

Class X():
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timer = Timer(timeout, self.some_method)
        self.timer.start()

    def some_method(self):
        # Do something

    def other_method(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.some_method()

import unittest

Class TestX(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_cancel_timer(self):
        x = X(1000)
        x.other_method()
        self.assertFalse(x.timer.is_alive())
```

Form the documentation the `is_alive` method returns True during the `run` operation;

> Return whether the thread is alive.
>   This method returns True just before the run() method starts until just after the run() method terminates. The module function enumerate() returns a list of all alive threads.

The documentation on the `cancel` method says the following;

> Stop the timer, and cancel the execution of the timer’s action. This will only work if the timer is still in its waiting stage.

Does this mean that the `cancel` method does not stop the `run` action? Or is is still in the grey area after the run method and returns True for that reason?

Comment: The cancelling operation costs some time (e.g. the lock allocated by timer should be released and stuff). If you add some pause after `x.other_method()` and before checking `x.timer.is_alive()` (e.g. `time.sleep(.1)`), the test should pass.

Comment: Hmm, okay this seems to work. But the method will never be called when the cancel method is run? E.g. the timer runs out exactly after the cancelling operation is executed and before the cancelling operation is done.

Comment: Once cancelling is triggered, the action will not be executed anymore; however, keep in mind that the time interval between two actions in timer is not guaranteed to be exactly the same as `timeout` you're passing in `Timer` constructor, so collisions are surely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `timer.is_alive()` you are just checking if the timer-thread itself is alive, so if you want to "check if `timer.cancel()` was called", you're testing for the wrong thing.

> Does this mean that the cancel method does not stop the run action?

It does not stop the `run()`-function, right. `timer.cancel()` just sets a flag in an `Event`-object which gets checked by `run`. You can test if the flag is set with:

```
self.assertTrue(x.timer.finished.is_set())
```

Unfortunately, checking for cancellation is not enough to prevent repeated execution, since `run` can have already crossed the check like you can see in the source code:

> ```
> # threading.py (Python 3.7.1):
>
> class Timer(Thread):
>     """Call a function after a specified number of seconds:
>
>             t = Timer(30.0, f, args=None, kwargs=None)
>             t.start()
>             t.cancel()     # stop the timer's action if it's still waiting
>
>     """
>
>     def __init__(self, interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None):
>         Thread.__init__(self)
>         self.interval = interval
>         self.function = function
>         self.args = args if args is not None else []
>         self.kwargs = kwargs if kwargs is not None else {}
>         self.finished = Event()
>
>     def cancel(self):
>         """Stop the timer if it hasn't finished yet."""
>         self.finished.set()
>
>     def run(self):
>         self.finished.wait(self.interval)
>         if not self.finished.is_set():
>             self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
>         self.finished.set()
> ```

Some more effort is needed to ensure unique execution. I've written up a possible solution to this in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54498024/9059420).