# Python timer start and reset

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, timer

I am attempting to get a Timer functionality to work in Python (Python 2.7 currently).

Here is what I have so far. I am struggling with a threading issue and resetting the timer.

```py
from threading import Timer

def api_call():
    print("Call that there api")

t = Timer(10.0,api_call)


def my_callback(channel):

    if something_true:
        print('reset timer and start again')
        t.cancel()
        t.start()
        print("\n timer started")
    elif something_else_true:
        t.cancel()
        print("timer canceled")
    else:
       t.cancel()
       print('cancel timer for sure')

try:
    if outside_input_that_can_happen_a_lot:
        my_callback()

finally:
    #cleanup objects
```

Basically, `my_callback()` can be called a lot of times very quickly and can hit any part of the "if", "elif", or "else" statements.

The issue I am having is that when the `something_true` variable is true, then it will start a timer. Which works great *the first time*. Every time after that that it is called, I get a threading error telling me that only one thread can be used for the timer.

Basically, I want to be able to reset my timer on the first "if" and cancel if the "elif" or "else" is hit.

Comment: Please add more concrete code instead of `outside_input_that_can_happen_a_lot`  and `something_true` etc

Comment: Hi @Devesh, I was trying to keep it as simple as possible. What code do you want?

Comment: You could try if my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54498024/9059420) works for you, it handles the resetting for you and you can simply `timelord.reset(interval)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my testing, this is because threads can only be started once, and as the timer relies on a thread, the timer can only be started once.
This means that the only way to re-start the timer would be to do:

```
def newTimer():
    global t
    t = Timer(10.0,api_call)
newTimer()
```

instead of the t = Timer part, and do

```
t.cancel()
newTimer()
t.start()
```

instead of the current re-start code.

This makes your full code:

```
from threading import Timer

def api_call():
    print("Call that there api")

def newTimer():
    global t
    t = Timer(10.0,api_call)
newTimer()


def my_callback(channel):

    if something_true:
        print('reset timer and start again')
        t.cancel()
        newTimer()
        t.start()
        print("\n timer started")
    elif something_else_true:
        t.cancel()
        print("timer canceled")
    else:
       t.cancel()
       print('cancel timer for sure')

try:
    if outside_input_that_can_happen_a_lot:
        my_callback()

finally:
    #cleanup objects
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @crazysqueak, does that mean that I may have tons of timers created? So each time that is called, do I hav 1+n Timers? Or just 1 Timer still?

Comment: Python automatically deletes objects (i.e. Timers) that aren't referenced by any variables. When newTimer() is run, t is set to a new Timer, and the old Timer is discarded as it no longer has any variables referencing it. This means that it will just be 1 timer still.